# Can not acces to \\$wsl WSL - Intellij IDEA can not reach JDK

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Windows installed Itellij IDEA can't reach JDK from Ubuntu (Ubuntu installed on WSL). Durning running app, I got this problem: 
[image]

And I can not reach \$wsl in Windows run (Start button + r).

Comment: I guess it can't reach it becasue IDEA runs java process as `...java.exe`. In WSL filesystems(at least at the specified path by you) there is no `exe` proceses

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: WSL is now supported and it should work just fine out of the box.

---

Original answer from 2020:

IntelliJ IDEA [has no support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223986) for the WSL JDK on Windows at the moment. Please use the locally installed JDK for Windows instead.